# Getting a field from an STL map iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std-pair

I have a map container to store certain objects, together with their name and type:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<ObjType, ObjBase*> > ObjContainer;
```

However, in many parts of the code, there are constructions like this:

```
ObjContainer::iterator it = mObjContainer.find(name);
if (it != mObjContainer.end()) {
    if (it->second.second) {
        it->second.second->setObj2Default();
        delete it->second.second;
        it->second.second = 0;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the many "it->second.second" are not very clear, and unmaintainable.
If it is changed in the future, to support one more field, for example, it will be all broken.
So, I am trying to change them by functions to access the fields, like this:

```
ObjBase*& getObjPtr(ObjContainer::iterator it) {
    return it->second.second;
}
```

Similarly, also function getObjName and getObjType.

It was also suggested to me that it would be more clear to have the iterator returning those fields:

```
 it.objPtr();
 it.objName();
 it.objType();
```

But I think that the STL iterators should not be inherited to have those functions, right? I see no other way to do it except to create a wrapper for the map and have its own iterator with those functions.

So, what would be the most appropriate option? Is there any other way to solve this problem that I am not seeing?

Comment: Why don't you just use a struct instead of a pair and name your fields they way you want?

Comment: @Spidey: Why roll your own class definitions if the library already comes with a perfectly serviceable one?

Comment: You could wrap'em with acessors. At least you'll get away with not using pair.first, pair.second, pair->second->second, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If the biggest problem is maintainability, I would replace the std::pair with a custom class/struct that wraps the ObjType and ObjBase* as one.

- it's easy to add a new field in the mix
- it's easy to access struct fields ObjType and ObjPair
- it's easy to write getters/setters/other functions for a class that handle ObjType and ObjPair

Answer (score 2):

I'd just make a local copy of the pointer (or reference) -- it'll probably be optimized out anyway:

```
ObjContainer::iterator const it = mObjContainer.find(name);
if (it != mObjContainer.end())
{
    ObjBase * & p = it->second.second;
    if (p) { p->foo(); delete p; p = NULL; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reference to simplify the syntax.

```
ObjContainer::iterator it = mObjContainer.find(name);
if (it != mObjContainer.end()) {
    std::pair<ObjType, ObjBase*> & ref = it->second;
    if (ref.second) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first question myself on whether ObjType is mandatory there.
If the aim is just to tell what kind of class is actually pointed by the second ObjBase* parameter of the pair, use `dynamic_cast` and get rid of the pair.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, ObjBase*> ObjContainer;
```

No more `second.second` in the code then:

```
ObjContainer::iterator it = mObjContainer.find(name);
if (it != mObjContainer.end()) {
    if (it->second) {
        it->second->setObj2Default();
        delete it->second;
        it->second = NULL;
    }
}
```

And when you need to test the actual type of the object:

```
ObjContainer::iterator it = mObjContainer.find(name);
if (it != mObjContainer.end()) {
    if (ChildObj* p_Child = dynamic_cast<ChildObj*>(it->second)) {
        // Work on p_Child...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the ObjType is needed, because sometimes the ObjBase* will be null, and they ObbType can be used to build a new instance using a factory.